# ld a.o b.o -e main -o ab doesn't work

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have two simple snippets:

a.c

```
extern int shared;

int main()
{
    int a = 100;
    swap(&a, &shared);
}
```

b.c

```
int shared = 1;

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

When I just use `gcc a.c b.c` then it works. But it fails when I use:

```
gcc -c a.c b.c
ld a.o b.o -e main -o ab
```

Running `./ab` will cause a `Segmentation fault` error. And it seems that the linker can not resolve `shared`. The result of `objdump -d ab` approves:

```
  4000f0:   c7 45 fc 64 00 00 00    movl   $0x64,-0x4(%rbp)
  4000f7:   48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
```

You can see address of `shared` is still `00 00 00`.

I think what I have done may lead to this error. What is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loose `-e`, you don't need it. `main` is *not* your entry point. It's just a function called first by the runtime system. The real entry point is in the runtime system and you don't even need to know what it is.

Comment: I have tried. But it will prompt a warning `can not find entry symbol _start;` and then run the executable file will still give `Segmentation fault`.@n.m.

Comment: Uh-oh, I forgot that you need to explicitly specify the standard library and the startup module. You normally don't want this. Just use `gcc a.o b.o -o ab`, this will call ld with the right arguments.

Comment: You're reading the objdump incorrectly. The section you list is simply moving '100' onto the stack, and storing its address in `rax`. That code corresponds to `a` within `main`. You may want to look at the `.data` section(s) to see what's there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the generated ELF is different from the standard (or atleast isn't compatible for running on your system), it misses quite a lot of standard ELF header sections. `readelf` can help you to find out the difference, for ex. do `gcc -o ab a.c b.c` then do `readelf -S ./ab` , you'll see there are 29 sections (as per my system). Also create another ELF through `gcc -c a.c b.c` and `ld a.o b.o -e main -o ab2`, then again use `readelf -S ./ab2` now you'll see there's only 18 section (as per my case).

Now if you take close look, then you'll see there's quite a few sections those are missing - like. .init, .fini, __libc_start_main etc. Now if you take a look at `objdump` of both executable's then you'll see at the time of returning there's few particular things which is done at .fini section (gcc internal stuffs, like restoring stack). So, these are the things which are missing from a standard ELF which is produces by invoking `gcc -o ab a.c b.c`.

To make sure that the problem is at the time of returning from main, you can make sure this by using `gdb`, I've figured the problem by generating object code by `gcc -g3 a.c b.c` and `ld a.o b.o -e main -o ab`. You'll see that problem is happening when you're about to return from main. Hope this will give you some idea, why it's happening.

Comment: gdb> layout asm ...does the trick. Guess it fails to find a return path from out of main()?

Comment: @kedar - yes, it seems to fails to find the return path from main.

Comment: I think your answer is right. It is the lacking of some sections in the ELF but not resolving the symbols. Thanks very much.@rakib

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the command that `gcc` actually executes to run the `ld` command, you can use the `-v` (verbose) option.  For example, for a single source file `zigzag7.c`, the compilation on Mac OS X 10.9.2 with GCC 4.8.1 produced:

```
$ gcc -v -std=c99 -o zigzag7 zigzag7.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/usr/gcc/v4.8.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.9.1' '-v' '-std=c99' '-o' 'zigzag7' '-mtune=core2'
 /usr/gcc/v4.8.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/cc1 -quiet -v -D__DYNAMIC__ zigzag7.c -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase zigzag7.c -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.1 -mtune=core2 -auxbase zigzag7 -std=c99 -version -o /var/folders/lj/kt7909lm8xj2tl001s6z265r0000gq/T//ccRar4iZ.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/gcc/v4.8.1/include
 /usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 48814df7d2c1a0636e2a53e05ef4ed75
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.9.1' '-v' '-std=c99' '-o' 'zigzag7' '-mtune=core2'
 as -arch x86_64 -force_cpusubtype_ALL -o /var/folders/lj/kt7909lm8xj2tl001s6z265r0000gq/T//ccVxV9gX.o /var/folders/lj/kt7909lm8xj2tl001s6z265r0000gq/T//ccRar4iZ.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/:/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../../:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.9.1' '-v' '-std=c99' '-o' 'zigzag7' '-mtune=core2'
 /usr/gcc/v4.8.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/collect2 -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.1 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o zigzag7 -L/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1 -L/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../.. /var/folders/lj/kt7909lm8xj2tl001s6z265r0000gq/T//ccVxV9gX.o -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
collect2 version 4.8.1
/usr/bin/ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.1 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o zigzag7 -L/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1 -L/usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../.. /var/folders/lj/kt7909lm8xj2tl001s6z265r0000gq/T//ccVxV9gX.o -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-224.1
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1
    /usr/gcc/v4.8.1/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
$
```

Note that it includes a number of system libraries, and a whole bunch of other options and controls.  While the details are almost certainly going to be different for your setup, the issues will be analogous; the `gcc` command adds a lot of options to the invocation of `ld` compared with your naïve invocation.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

1. Manually set [dynamic linker](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

   ```
   -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2
   ```
2. Include C runtime

   - `crt1` : _start symbol (or crt0, crt2 ...)
   - `crti` : function prologs for the .init and .fini sections (_init and _fini symbols)
   - `crtn` : function epilogs for the .init/.fini sections
3. Use `-lc` to link several object files

Final command (on my 32-bit Intel):

```
ld -o ab \
-dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 \
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o \
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o \
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o \
a.o b.o -lc
```

---

Using the `-v` option for gcc as mentioned by Jonathan Leffler, or `-###` to only print. Should give you the paths for the above mentioned.

---

### More in detail

#### crtN

This has the `_start` function (symbol) that initializes the process. It typically set up the environment for the initial execution of the program (bootsrap). Also *argc, argv, env, stack / frame pointer etc.* if not done by loader.

Initializes standard library. Memory handling, I/O etc.

Calls `_init` which calls global *constructor* functions.

Finally in the start sequence it calls *main* with `argc` and `argv`.

When *main* concludes `_fini` is called which call global *destructor* functions.

---

### Minimalism

In this concrete example we can also do a minimal *crt* with ([ref. OS Dev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_C_Library#Program_Initialization))

For i386:

```
.section .text

.global _start
_start:
        movl $0, %ebp
        pushl %ebp
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        call main
        movl %eax, %edi
        call exit
```

or even:

```
.section .text

.global _start
_start:
        call main
        call exit
```

For 64:

```
.section .text

.global _start
_start:
        movq $0, %rbp
        pushq %rbp
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp, %rbp
        call main
        movl %eax, %edi
        call exit
```

Build and run:

```
as crt_min.S -o crt_min.o
ld -o ab -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 crt_min.o a.o b.o -lc
./ab
```

## Bare minimum

To get rid of dynamic-linker we can use something like:

```
.global _start
_start:
        call main
        call exit
        nop
exit:
        movl $1, %eax    # sys_exit
        xorl %ebx, %ebx  # exit code
        int $0x80        # call kernel
```

Build and run:

```
as crt_min.S -o crt_min.o
ld -o ab crt_min.o a.o b.o 
./ab
```

Answer (score 0):

Though other answers are great and I have accepted one, I want to post my own research on it.

Why there is a `Segmentation fault` is that **the ELF is incomplete**.

Using the `ld` in that way will produce an incomplete ELF file. To see this, we can compare it with file produced by `gcc`. The former lacks many sections.

After `main` is executed, there is still something to be executed. But unfortunately, my ELF file does not get that section. So, something wrong will be executed and then generates an error. When I use `gdb` to debug it I find the error is produced after `main`.

And from another aspect I can approve my point, let's define our own `exit` function, so we will not return to the system after `main` and nothing will be executed then:

```
void exit()
{
    asm("movl $42, %ebx \n\t"
    "movl $1, %eax \n\t"
    "int $0x80 \n\t"
    );
}
```

And then add `exit` to `main`. Finally the file is able to run, with no exceptions.